# Get the total number of moving average crosses over a period of time and plot a label on the area it occurs

Tags: pine-script, trading

(I'm new at this, so sorry for the shit code.)

I'm trying to get the total number of Moving average crosses that occur over a period of time, compare that number to a user-defined 'count' and then plot a label to the chart in the area that those crosses happen. (the idea is 'many crosses in a short period of time = sideways market')

Here is what i've got so far. Thank you for any help, in advance!!

```
    testvar3 = input(title="CompareNum", type=input.integer, defval=2, group="TestGroup")// Compaire number
testvar0 = input(title="inputfunctestLONG", type=input.integer, defval=10, group="TestGroup") //Look back period
MehValue0 = longCross ? 1 : 0 //convert Bool to int
longCrosses = sum(MehValue0,testvar0) // Calculate the number of crosses over a given period
testvar1 = input(title="inputfunctestSHORT", type=input.integer, defval=10, group="TestGroup") //look back period
MehValue1 = shortCross ? 1 : 0 
shortCrosses = sum(MehValue1,testvar1)
shortLongSum = longCrosses + shortCrosses //total number of crosses

LabelCrossTest = if (longCross or shortCross and shortLongSum > testvar0)
    label.new(x=bar_index, y=na, yloc=yloc.abovebar, text="Sideways Detection Test", style=label.style_label_down, color=color.green, size=size.normal)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work as intended if you just change the last section

```
if (longCross or shortCross) and shortLongSum > testvar3
    label.new(x=bar_index, y=na, yloc=yloc.abovebar, text="Sideways Detection Test", style=label.style_label_down, color=color.green, size=size.normal)
```

It's a good idea to give your variables more descriptive names to make it easier to track what you are doing. So instead of `testvar3`, `threshold` or `minimumCrosses` etc

Comment: First off, thank you very much!  It does work as intended. However, I'm not sure why the placement of the () changes the expression so much? I thought they were optional in pine script if statements.

Comment: The parentheses aren't optional they are used to modify the logic expression. `(longCross or shortCross and shortLongSum > testvar3)` is equivalent to `longCross or (shortCross and shortLongSum > testvar3)`. While `(longCross or shortCross) and shortLongSum > testvar3)` is equivalent to `(longCross and shortLongsum > testvar3) or (shortCross and shortLongSum > testvar3)`